# How to return data from a function

Tags: javascript, return

I'm trying to solve the following Kata:

> a 2 digit number, if you add the digits together, multiply by 3, add 45 and reverse.

I'm unable to figure out how to return the data from my function so that I can later assign the value to an HTML element.

This is my code.

```
function daily() {
   for(var j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
       function teaser(num) {
           var x = num;
           var y = x.toString().split("");
           if(y.length == 2) {
               var sum = parseInt(y[0]) + parseInt(y[1]);
               if(sum * 3 == x) {
                   console.log(x + " is equal to 3 times " + sum);
                   var addFortyFive = x + 45;
                   console.log("Adding 45 to " + x + " gives " + addFortyFive);
                   var reversal = parseInt(addFortyFive.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
                   console.log("'The 2 digit number " + x + ", is 3 times the sum (" + sum + ") of its digits. If 45 is added to " + x + ", the result is " + addFortyFive + ". If the digits are reversed, the number is... " + reversal + ".");
               }
           } else {
               console.log("Not a 2 digit Number!!");
           }
       }
       teaser(j);
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I reduced the noise in your question so that it is more concise. It's good that you have your code, but please be more concise with your question. Everyone's questions are of immediate concern to them. It's alright.

Comment: okay thank you, i was actually just reading up on how to ask questions better in the e-mail that stack sent me. i appreciate it

Comment: You should use an array to store the values and try using return keyword.

Comment: The part that I have highlighted is a little ambiguous. Is that what they gave you on the site? Do you really only want to use the values that are equal to three times their sum?

Comment: What you want to return from the function, you could  return anything using return statement just before function closing parenthesis.

Comment: yes, I wrote the code to find the number that works for the problem, which is  "a number that is 2 digits, and the sum of the digits times 3 + 45 reversed, and the solution is 27. Add 45 to 27 is 72, reversed it is 27. the same thing.

Comment: but what i am trying to do is return the value 27 so that I can display the result in someplace other than the console.

Comment: i tried putting "return reversal" at the end of the teaser function, I also tried it in the if statement, I even tried putting a return statement at the beginning of the teaser function as "return num" to just see if it would at least return the input for the function itself when called with the for loop in daily, but nothing comes up anywhere

Comment: and yeah, the highlighted part is just that, It was a simple brain teaser, i just wanted to see if i could code it out and it turned into this whole big thing now. any help is really appreciated. I did all this in the console in chrome.dev.

Comment: is the return statement maybe not working because I am using it in a nested if statement? and I tried 'return reversal' at the end before the closing parenthesis and still nothing\

Comment: Syam Babu, I did what you said, I declared an array, added 27 to it, and tried to return the array, and that doesn't return anything either. Im seriously stuck. Im gonna call it a night and check back in the morning. Thanks everybody that commented already, and in advance for any comments/help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so my issue has been solved! Thanks all of you, especially krillgar, so I had to alter the code you gave me krillgar, a little bit in order to populate the results array with only the numbers (one number in this case) that satisfy the parameters of the daily tease I was asking about. yours was populating with 89 undefined and on number, 27 because it is the only number that works.

One of my problems was that I was expecting the return statement to not only save a value, but also show it on the screen, but what I was not realizing was that I needed a place to store the value. In your code you created a result array to populate with the correct numbers. And also, I needed a variable to store the data for each iteration of the for loop cycling through 10 - 100. Anyways, you gave me what I needed to figure this out and make it do what I wanted it to do, and all is well in the world again.

Anyway, thank you all for your help and input, and I will always remember to make sure I have somewhere to store the answers, and also somewheres to store the value of each loop iteration in order to decide which numbers to push into the results array and save it so it can be displayed and/or manipulated for whatever purpose it may be. I guess I was just so busy thinking about the fact that when I returned num it didn't show the value, instead of thinking about the fact that I needed to store the value. Here is the final code for this problem and thanks again peoples!

```
function daily() {
var results = [];
for(var j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
    function teaser(num) {
        var x = num;
        var y = x.toString().split("");
        if(y.length == 2) {
            var sum = parseInt(y[0]) + parseInt(y[1]);
            if(sum * 3 == x) {
                console.log(x + " is equal to 3 times " + sum);
                var addFortyFive = x + 45;
                console.log("Adding 45 to " + x + " gives " + addFortyFive);
                var reversal = parseInt(addFortyFive.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
                console.log("'The 2 digit number " + x + ", is 3 times the sum (" + sum + ") of its digits. If 45 is added to " + x + ", the result is " + addFortyFive + ". If the digits are reversed, the number is... " + reversal + ".");
                return num;
                // Here you have one that is correct, so return it:
           } else {
                console.log(num + " does not fulfill function parameters");
                // This is just so you can visualize the numbers
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    var answer = teaser(j);
    if(answer != null) {
        results.push(answer);
    }
}
return results;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

From your question I'm guessing you need `reversal` value on function daily for loop.

Would recommend you to take out function teaser from inside for-loop, this will make code much cleaner and easy to understand and you can do like:

```
function daily() {
   for(var j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
       var teaser = teaser(j);
       // Can now use anything returned from teaser function here
   }
}

function teaser(num) {
     var x = num;
     var y = x.toString().split("");
     if(y.length == 2) {
         var sum = parseInt(y[0]) + parseInt(y[1]);
         if(sum * 3 == x) {
             console.log(x + " is equal to 3 times " + sum);
             var addFortyFive = x + 45;
             console.log("Adding 45 to " + x + " gives " + addFortyFive);
             var reversal = parseInt(addFortyFive.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
             console.log("'The 2 digit number " + x + ", is 3 times the sum (" + sum + ") of its digits. If 45 is added to " + x + ", the result is " + addFortyFive + ". If the digits are reversed, the number is... " + reversal + ".");

             return reversal;
         }
     } else {
         console.log("Not a 2 digit Number!!");
         return false;
     }
 }
```

If don't want to take function out then you can do this:

```
function daily() {
   for(var j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
       function teaser(num) {
           var x = num;
           var y = x.toString().split("");
           if(y.length == 2) {
               var sum = parseInt(y[0]) + parseInt(y[1]);
               if(sum * 3 == x) {
                   console.log(x + " is equal to 3 times " + sum);
                   var addFortyFive = x + 45;
                   console.log("Adding 45 to " + x + " gives " + addFortyFive);
                   var reversal = parseInt(addFortyFive.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
                   console.log("'The 2 digit number " + x + ", is 3 times the sum (" + sum + ") of its digits. If 45 is added to " + x + ", the result is " + addFortyFive + ". If the digits are reversed, the number is... " + reversal + ".");

                   return reversal;
               }
           } else {
               console.log("Not a 2 digit Number!!");
               return false;
           }
       }

       var teaser = teaser(j);
       // Can now use anything returned from teaser function here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning something from a function is very simple!

Just add the `return` statement to your function.

```js
function sayHello(name) {
 return 'Hello ' + name + '!';
}

console.log(sayHello('David'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As was said in the comments of the question, because you're going to (most likely) have multiple answers that match your condition, you will need to store those in an array. Your `teaser` function returns individual results, where `daily` will check all the numbers in your range.

```
function daily() {
    var results = [];
   for(var j = 10; j < 100; j++) {
       function teaser(num) {
           var x = num;
           var y = x.toString().split("");
           if(y.length == 2) {
               var sum = parseInt(y[0]) + parseInt(y[1]);
               if(sum * 3 == x) {
                   console.log(x + " is equal to 3 times " + sum);
                   var addFortyFive = x + 45;
                   console.log("Adding 45 to " + x + " gives " + addFortyFive);
                   var reversal = parseInt(addFortyFive.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
                   console.log("'The 2 digit number " + x + ", is 3 times the sum (" + sum + ") of its digits. If 45 is added to " + x + ", the result is " + addFortyFive + ". If the digits are reversed, the number is... " + reversal + ".");

                    // Here you have one that is correct, so return it:
                    return num;
               } else {
                    // Make sure we don't return undefined for when the sum 
                    // times three doesn't equal the number.
                    return null;
                }
           } else {
               console.log("Not a 2 digit Number!!");
                return null;
           }
       }
       var answer = teaser(j);

        if (answer !== null) {
            results.push(answer);
        }
   }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: ahhh!! thank you! The only thing was It gave me an array with 98 undefined, and only one index with a value of 27, which is the number that the teaser was looking for. So I changed the line that pushes the answer if it is != null to != undefined. But either way it solved my issue.

Comment: Ah, right. That's because those 98 numbers have a length of 2, so they hit that outer `if` statement, but fail on the crucial inner `if`. Good catch, and that's great you were able to figure that out. I'll add the other `else` to the answer.